# MS Access enter data in 1 field of a form that then produces a default predefined value in another field

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am using MS Access 2007.

I have a table within a database, the 3 fields of concern are:

Field 1 = Date Location open (Date)

Field 2 = Date Location closed (Date)

Field 3 = Status (Text)

I need guidance on the best method for the following:

At form entry level as soon as a user enters a date in the date location open field,
the Status field changes to display the text "Active" in its field.

As soon as the user enters a date in the Date Location closed field the Status field changes from "Active" to "Inactive".

This happens for each record added to the table.

I have played around with various validation rules at table level hoping to have a rule or expression in place before I created the form. 
That did not work I think it is at form level and maybe the answer is like this:

[Ms Access 1 field triggering data for another field](http://www.accessforums.net/forms/calculate-one-field-based-another-one-9373.html)

Or should I look at generating code that declares 2 strings  "Active" and  "Inactive" then use IF Date Location open has Date value then add "Active" string to field.

Or am i overlooking the obvious and its as simple as a combo box....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the after update event of the "date opened" text box to set the value of the "status" text box.  If that text box is named "txtStatus", a simple assignment statement could be:

```
Me.txtStatus = "Active"
```

However, you might want to first verify "date closed" is Null.  Otherwise, an "Inactive" record would be set as "Active" again if a user subsequently changes the "date opened" value.

Also consider whether Null is to be permitted for "date opened" and what should happen if an existing value is changed to Null.

Similarly, use the after update event of the "date closed" text box to adjust the value of `txtStatus`.  However, the logic there will likely differ from that of the "date opened" after update event.

Comment: Yes thankyou that works now looking into a work around regarding deleting and re entering values and how to best implement that process with the status text